# Green's function of an equation of motion of $\zeta$ field

Tags: differential-equations, greens-functions, cosmological-inflation

I'm writing a thesis on inflationary cosmology. I've come across a background equation of motion of my $\zeta$ field of the form
$$
\partial_\tau(z^2(\tau)\partial_\tau\zeta_{\textbf k}(\tau)) + k^2z^2(\tau)\zeta_{\textbf k}(\tau) = 0,
$$
where $z^2(\tau) := a^2(\tau)\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ has the usual definition of $-\dot H / H^2$. I'm working in slow roll inflation.

I would like to know the Green's function of this PDE and I haven't really found any sources. Any help would be appreciated :)